# jade extend and include overwrites files for no reason

Tags: javascript, pug

SlideBase.jade

```
.slideWrap
    .slideInner
         block slides
```

slideSet1.jade

```
extends SlideBase

append slides
    .slide set1slide1
    .slide set1slide2
    .slide set1slide3
```

slideSet2.jade

```
extends SlideBase

append slides
    .slide set2slide1
    .slide set2slide2
    .slide set2slide3
```

output.jade

```
#mySlides
    p some copy
    #slideZone
          include slideSet1.jade
          include slideSet2.jade
```

expected result:

```
<div id="mySlides>
    <p>some copy</p>
    <div id="slideZone>
         <div class="slideWrap>
              <div class="slideInner>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide1</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide2</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide3</div>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="slideWrap>
              <div class="slideInner>
                    <div class="slide">set2slide1</div>
                    <div class="slide">set2slide2</div>
                    <div class="slide">set2slide3</div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

actual result:

```
<div id="mySlides>
    <p>some copy</p>
    <div id="slideZone>
         <div class="slideWrap>
              <div class="slideInner>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide1</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide2</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide3</div>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="slideWrap>
              <div class="slideInner>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide1</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide2</div>
                    <div class="slide">set1slide3</div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rather than getting slideSet2.jade, jade compiler just repeats slideSet1.jade in its place. What am I doing wrong here?

**DISCLOSURE:**

I am running on Codekit with Jade version 0.27.2; and any accepted answer much address why its not working in my environment.

Comment: I got the same results, I think you've found a bug. I compiled it to JavaScript to get an insight and the JS does show this bug:

[Line 67](https://gist.github.com/4032320#L67) contains `slideSet2.jade` (filename to print debug info) but [line 82](https://gist.github.com/4032320#L82) contains the contents of slideSet1.jade.

Comment: I don't understand quite where the bug is. Should I report this to the jade project or the codekit project?

Comment: It's jade for sure. Your test case is quite representative of the issue, the bug occurs when you include two subclasses of one same class. I had a glance at [jade's issues](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/search?q=include) and I didn't see this bug but you want to double-check

Comment: @guillaume they verified its in the version of codekit I am using and has been addressed by jade. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I stand corrected; I should have updated my jade version before answering that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in a newer version of jade. And CodeKit's version should be brought up to date.